# How to remove entry "Listings" from table of content (toc)

Tags: listings, table-of-contents, memoir

How can I use `\lstlistoflistings` to create a list of listings, but not have this list as an entry in the table of content?

Normally, a star helps to hide things like that and I use *memoir* as document class which supports and helps hiding lists like `\tableofcontents*`, `\listoffigures*`, `\listoftables*`, ... But adding the star like that: `\lstlistoflistings*` does not help.

I don't want to patch any of the class file or other packages if not really needed. (I use *tex* seldom enough to get annoyed if I want to have the listings list in the toc and then can't remember anymore what I changed).

At the moment I use *latexmk* to typeset my files. And so I currently have a *.latexmkrc* file with a hook that delete this entry from the content before it gets added to the toc, like this:

```
add_cus_dep("toc", "toc", 0, "removelistingfromtoc");
sub removelistingfromtoc {
  $origin = "$_[0].toc";
  $dest = "$_[0].toc.unpatched";
  system("mv '$origin' '$dest' && grep -v '\\contentsline.*{List of Listings}' ".
         "'$dest' > '$origin'");
  return 0;
}
```

This removes for example the following line from the toc file:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Listings}{}{section*.3}
```

*(I changed the name "Listing" to "List of Listings". Btw: Any author with english as their native language might help me to critic if this "List of Listings" is a proper and common term)*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `memoir` class, the lists seem to be defined in terms of `\newlistof`, and since the `listings` package implements `\lstlistoflistings` by retrofitting `\tableofcontents`, it should be possible to redefine it the `memoir` way:

```
\newlistof{lstlistoflistings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
```

And then simply add the `*` as you said. **Note** that I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your tip did the job. The Listing is not anymore included in the TOC and I can latexmkrc hack. Here a snippet of what's left now:

    :
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Listings}
    \newlistof{lstlistoflistings}{lol}{\lstlistlistingname}
    :
    \begin{document}
    \lstlistoflistings*
    :

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.

Comment: @grddev BTW, very good answer! Wouldn't you consider becoming more active here on TeX.SX?